# Closure Compiler Service API

Tags: vb.net, http, post, google-closure-compiler

Trying to intergrate the closure compiler service into one of my applications and having some issues.

Error being returned is "(413) Request Entity Too Large." Sounds reasonable but I know for a fact the service accepts files larger then the one I am sending it.

```
    Private _HttpWebRequest As HttpWebRequest
Private _Result As StringBuilder
Private Const ClosureWebServiceURL As String = "http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/compile?output_format=xml&output_info=compiled_code" &
                                                                    "&output_info=warnings" &
                                                                    "&output_info=errors" &
                                                                    "&output_info=statistics" &
                                                                    "&compilation_level=ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS" &
                                                                    "&warning_level=default" &
                                                                    "&js_code={0}"





_Result = New StringBuilder
_HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(String.Format(ClosureWebServiceURL, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_Script))), HttpWebRequest)
_HttpWebRequest.Method = "POST"
_HttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
_HttpWebRequest.ContentLength = 0

Dim response As WebResponse = _HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Using responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream
     Dim encoding As Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
     Using readStream As New StreamReader(responseStream, encoding)
          Dim read(256) As Char
          Dim count As Integer = readStream.Read(read, 0, 256)
          While count > 0
              Dim str As New String(read, 0, count)
              _Result.Append(str)
              count = readStream.Read(read, 0, 256)
          End While
     End Using
End Using
```

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your request data over to the POST's `RequestStream` instead of using the querystring.

```
Private _HttpWebRequest As HttpWebRequest
Private _Result As StringBuilder
Private Const ClosureWebServiceURL As String = "http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/compile?"
Private Const ClosureWebServicePOSTData As String = "output_format=xml&output_info=compiled_code" &
                                                                "&output_info=warnings" &
                                                                "&output_info=errors" &
                                                                "&output_info=statistics" &
                                                                "&compilation_level=ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS" &
                                                                "&warning_level=default" &
                                                                "&js_code={0}"


    '//Build's a large javascript for testing
    Dim _Script As String = ""
    For I = 1 To 100
        _Script &= "function hello_" & I & "(name) {  alert('Hello, ' + name);}hello('New user');"
    Next

    '//Create the POST data
    Dim Data = String.Format(ClosureWebServicePOSTData, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_Script))

    _Result = New StringBuilder
    _HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(ClosureWebServiceURL), HttpWebRequest)
    _HttpWebRequest.Method = "POST"
    _HttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    '//Set the content length to the length of the data. This might need to change if you're using characters that take more than 256 bytes
    _HttpWebRequest.ContentLength = Data.Length
    '//Write the request stream
    Using SW As New StreamWriter(_HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
        SW.Write(Data)
    End Using


    Dim response As WebResponse = _HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

    Using responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream
        Dim encoding As Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
        Using readStream As New StreamReader(responseStream, encoding)
            Dim read(256) As Char
            Dim count As Integer = readStream.Read(read, 0, 256)
            While count > 0
                Dim str As New String(read, 0, count)
                _Result.Append(str)
                count = readStream.Read(read, 0, 256)
            End While
        End Using
    End Using


    Trace.WriteLine(_Result)
```

Comment: Legand! thank you... I should have worked that out. Gotta stop working so late. :-)